# Show irreducible in k(x,y)[z]

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

k is a field and $n\geq 1$. Show that $z^n+y^3+x^2 \in k(x,y)[z]$ is irreducible.

Can someone give hints? I am not sure how to apply Eisenstein's criterion to show irreducibility. Thank you

Comment: What is the characteristic of $k$? It doesn't matter so much, but it would be helpful to mention.

Comment: @AlexWertheim it is not given in the problem

Comment: @user37014 Do you mean $k[x,y][z]$ or $k(x,y)[z]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eisenstein's criterion works, since $y^3+x^2$  is irreducible in $k[x,y]$, for degree reasons (y^3 can have no square root in $k[y]$).